# Can I have an indeterminate number of destructuring lists in a lisp macro lambda list?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, destructuring, clisp

I'm trying to write a macro that expands to an unspecified number of function calls, but I also want to be able to specify exactly one argument to be passed to each function in the macro call. I would basically want its syntax to look like a `let` call:

```
(let ((var1 1)
      (var2 2)
      ...
      (varn n))
  body)
```

but passing arguments to functions instead of binding variables, so a call like this

```
(foo ((fn1 arg1)
      (fn2 arg2)
      ...
      (fnn argn))
  body)
```

expands to this:

```
(progn
  (funcall fn1 arg1)
  (funcall fn2 arg2)
  ...
  (funcall fnn argn)
  body)
```

As far as I can tell, the list-destructuring behaviour of macro lambda lists allows me to pass an unspecified number of forms to the macro in a nested lambda list:

```
(defmacro foo ((&rest call-forms) &body body)
  ...)
```

OR define a rigid syntax for a form in a nested lambda list:

```
(defmacro foo ((single-fn single-arg) &body body)
  ...)
```

but NOT both:

```
(defmacro foo ((&rest (fn arg)) &body body) ; gibberish
  ...)
```

Is there a loophole or workaround I'm not seeing? I know it seems arbitrary, but the call syntax I specified above would be ideal for what I'm doing. I get that this might be out of the question, since `let` is a special operator and its behaviour appears to be unique, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to to `(map () 'funcall (list f1 f2) (list arg1 arg2))`, maybe there is a way to do this without a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can completely drop lambda-list destructuring... I suggest this solution:

```
(defmacro funcall-macro (pairs &body body)
  (handler-case `(progn ,@(mapcar (lambda (pair)
                                    (destructuring-bind (fname arg) pair
                                      (list 'funcall fname arg)))
                                  pairs)
                   ,@body)
    (error (e) (error (format nil "~a~%" e)))))
```

With `destructuring-bind`, I check that each pair has exactly two elements.

Test:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(funcall-macro ((f1 a1)
                              (f2 a2)
                              (fn an))
                         (b1)
                         (b2)
                         (bn)))

(PROGN (FUNCALL F1 A1) (FUNCALL F2 A2) (FUNCALL FN AN) (B1) (B2) (BN))
T
```

This macro also works for `pairs` equal to `()`.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the answer I was looking for; I assume the `destructuring-bind` in the body of the `funcall-macro` definition will still rigidly enforce the syntax I wanted for calls to `funcall-macro` as desired. The rest is "abstracted away," as they say, so that's fine with me!

Comment: Nice answer. Instead of calling  `(error (format nil "~a~%" e))` you could simply `(error "~a~%" e)`

Comment: @JérômeRadix : why not remove the HANDLER-CASE and ERROR if it doesn't do anything interesting?

Comment: You could at least use (&rest pairs) instead of just pairs, to indicate that you are expecting a list, not just an atom.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, you won't be able to specify that in the lambda-list.
What is customary to do, instead of using `(&rest clauses)`, (which would also allow for 0 clauses), is to specify the form of the first clause, and document that all the following should have the same form.  So:

```
(defmacro foo (((fname argument) &rest other-fname-arguments) &body body)
  ;; check the form of the others-fname-argument
  (handler-case (every (lambda (fname-argument)
            (destructuring-bind (fname argument) fname-argument
              (declare (ignore fname argument))
              t))
                       other-fname-arguments)
    (error ()
      (error "The form of the other-fname-argument is not correct, it should be a list of (fname argument).")))
  (let ((fname-arguments (cons (list fname argument) other-fname-arguments)))
    `(progn
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (fname-argument)
                   (destructuring-bind (fname argument) fname-argument
                     (list 'funcall fname argument)))
                 fname-arguments)
       ,@body)))


(setf *print-right-margin* 30)

(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(foo ((f1 a1)
                              (f2 a2)
                              (fn an))
                         (b1)
                         (b2)
                         (bn))))

(progn
 (funcall f1 a1)
 (funcall f2 a2)
 (funcall fn an)
 (b1)
 (b2)
 (bn))
```

Comment: It seems that '(error "The form of the other-fname-argument is not correct, it should be a list of (fname argument).")' is not called when an error is raised. Do you know why ?

Comment: I see why your error condition may not be catched by handler-case, it is when the first function does not have an argument, then the defmacro raises an error condition before your handler-case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I hinted at with: "instead of using (&rest clauses), (which would also allow for 0 clauses)".

Answer (score 0):

One other interesting way to deal with this problem is to write a macro which checks *one* pair and then expands into a form which uses the same macro to check the rest.  A natural way to do this is by pattern matching, and this example uses [`destructuring-match`](https://tfeb.github.io/dsm/) to do this, as it was specifically designed for processing macro forms in this way.

```
(defmacro foo (clauses &body forms)
  (destructuring-match clauses
    (()
     `(progn ,@forms))
    (((f a) &rest more)
     `(progn
        (funcall ,f ,a)
        (foo ,more ,@forms)))
    (otherwise
     (error "what even is this?"))))
```

Now `(foo ((a 1) (b 2)) x)` will expand into

```
(progn
  (funcall a 1)
  (progn
    (funcall b 2)
    (progn x)))
```

Which is equivalent to what you want.  There's no need to worry about all the nested `progn`s: the compiler will deal with those.

If `(foo () ...)` should not be legal, then you need something like this:

```
(defmacro foo (clauses &body forms)
  (destructuring-match clauses
    (((f a))
     `(progn
        (funcall ,f ,a)
        ,@forms))
    (((f a) &rest more)
     `(progn
        (funcall ,f ,a)
        (foo ,more ,@forms)))
    (otherwise
     (error "what even is this?"))))
```

---

You can also use `destructuring-match` as a more flexible but probably slower `destructuring-bind`.  In particular you can implement one of the other solutions without the annoyance of having to catch the error if you want your own error message or condition:

```
(defmacro foo (clauses &body forms)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (clause)
                 (destructuring-match clause
                   ((f a)
                    `(funcall ,f ,a))
                   (otherwise
                    (error "what even is this?"))))
               clauses)
     ,@forms))
```

Using either approach you can support more flexible syntax of course, so you could have something like what `let` does (although this would be hard to get right for this specific macro I think).